# How to change Prestashop 1.7 table prefix?

Tags: php, prestashop

I tried to change `define('_DB_PREFIX_', 'ps_');` in `/config/settings.inc.php`, but my `settings.inc.php` file is empty.

I tried set that `define`, is working, but where is saved my first configuration?

How can I change table prefix in Prestashop 1.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new version of PrestaShop is migrating to the symfony framework. The configuration file that you should to change is located in:

`rootofps/app/config/parameters.php`

Hope it helps :)